# What is the 'Form' returned by PyQt6.uic.loadUiType()?

Tags: python, pyqt6

Reading the documentation. Confused as to what this is. Can kind of work with it but don't want to be cargo-culty.

```
PyQt6.uic.loadUiType(uifile)

    Load a Qt Designer .ui file and return a tuple of the generated form class and the Qt base class. These can then be used to create any number of instances of the user interface without having to parse the .ui file more than once.

    Parameters

        uifile (str) – the file name or file-like object containing the .ui file.
    Returns

        the **form class** and the Qt base class.
```

Thanx!

Comment: "cargo-culty"? The form class is an abstract class that can build the UI on a given (and compatible) Qt widget instance. It can be used as a separate object, or with multiple inheritance along with the Qt class. See [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.